# Put Treeviews in TabControl content pages

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm currently building a XML editor and now I want to implement the ability to open and edit multiple XML files concurrently. Every file should be represented by a tab in a TabControl while the content of the tab shows a hierarchical TreeView of the XML structure.

Since I'm in no way an expert on XAML data binding I'm having trouble to populate the treeview from the view model object I already implemented.

**My window:**

```
public partial class EditorWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<FileTab> tabList;

    public EditorWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        xsdManager = null;
        tabList = new ObservableCollection<FileTab>();

        editorWindow.DataContext = tabList;
        tabControl.ItemsSource = tabList;

        FileTab pt = new FileTab(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Test.xml");
        tabList.Add(pt);
        refreshTabControl();

    }

    private void OpenButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xml";
        fileDialog.Filter = "XML files (.xml)|*.xml";
        Nullable<bool> result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = fileDialog.FileName;
            Console.WriteLine("MainWindow.SchemaButtonClick:: " + filename);

            tabList.Add(new FileTab(filename));
            Console.WriteLine("New Tab: " + Path.GetFileName(filename));

            refreshTabControl();
        }
    }

    private void refreshTabControl()
    {
        tabControl.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

**My Window XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="XmlTool.EditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XmlTool"
        Title="EditorWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Name="editorWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="OpenButtonClick">Open XML</Button>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding tabList}" Height="200">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TreeView Name="xmlTreeView">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding treeRoot}" DataType="{x:Type local:XElementViewModel}">
                                <Label Name="elementNameLabel" Content="{Binding ElementName=treeRoot, Path=name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>                        
                    </TreeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The class XElementViewModel is the view model for an XElement and contains all child elements in a List of XElementViewmodel objects.

**Class FileTab:**

```
class FileTab
    {
        public string header { get; set; }
        public XElementViewModel treeRoot { get; set; }

        public FileTab()
        {
            header = "Default tab";
            treeRoot = new XElementViewModel(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\ExampleXMLs\Test.xml");
        }

        public FileTab(string path) 
        {
            header = Path.GetFileName(path);
            Console.WriteLine("ProjectTab: header = " + header);
            treeRoot = new XElementViewModel(path);
            Console.WriteLine("ProjectTab: treeRoot.name = " + treeRoot.name);
        }
    }
```

The current code correctly adds new tabs named like the opened file, but it doesn't display the Treeview at all. As I said I'm not that good with data binding so any advice about that would help!

Comment: Your treeView needs to set its ItemsSource to the "treeRoot". But that's just the start of your problems - you need to create a hierarchical data template for each time that XElementViewModel contains. And in each of these you specify how to find the children nodes, via the ItemsSource attribute.

Comment: To get some further informations on what is happening you could use an application like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) that way  you could look at the structure of your Window and figure out if, maybe, your treeview is there but is invisible/has a size of 0,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I got it to work by playing around with the bindings a bit. With the below XAML it displays the TreeView with the XML structure and switched between the corresponding trees when selecting tabs.

```
<Window x:Class="XmlTool.EditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XmlTool"
        Title="EditorWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Name="editorWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="OpenButtonClick">Open XML</Button>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding tabList}" Height="200">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TreeView Name="xmlTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding treeRoot.childrenList}">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding childrenList}" DataType="{x:Type local:XElementViewModel}">                                       
                                    <Label Name="elementNameLabel" Content="{Binding name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```